# My app doesn't see an internal file

Tags: android, permissions, system, crash-reports, file-read

I want my app to check the last modified date of a file and read it, but it acts like the file doesn't exist even though I know it's there. This is my code:

```
File f = new File("data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1528276030506.txt");
    if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("I see you");
      }
    System.out.println("Before Format : " + f.lastModified());
```

I have READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_LOGS permissions in my manifest and have also given them through adb (adb shell pm grant package android.permission), I also have root access.

What to do?

Comment: Are you missing a leading '`/`' in the filename?

Comment: With or without it I get the same result. I've tested and I can see other files from the same device without using a leading / so it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to the following and use the `getFileStreamPath` method

```
     File file = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
    if(file == null || !file.exists()) {
         // Do something 
     }else{
        // Do something else 
     }
```

Or the `openFileInput` method

```
try {
  FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(String filename);
  // ... do something
try {
    fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Those gave me a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator".    I looked at how to fix it and saw a suggestion of using "FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (new File("/data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1528276030506.txt"));"  but that doesn't work either and I get a permission denied error.

Comment: actually "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator"  means that the file was found and cannot be open  in the private data area of the application or any other sub directories so my question are you sure about root access  ? OR the file path is wrong can you try with // instead of / ? But i think that you don't have permission that's your issue

Comment: Maybe you're right. Unfortunately I can't test it right now. Tomorrow I'll be able to.

Comment: OK, so an update: for me to grant root permission to the app it has to ask for it first, but this piece of code doesn't trigger such a request, it just fails. I have some other code in the app that does ask for root access and I grant it to it but still I get the same error for file reading even though it should be getting the root access as well. I also used the terminal to grant reading and writing permission to this file to everyone, but still my app can't read it :( I've checked multiple times and it does exist at that location.

Comment: What abou tthe "//" instead of "/" same issue ?

Comment: Yeah. I can use the same syntax I've given at the top to access some other files but not the crash reports.